# How to initialize an arraylist of Hashmap?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'm really new to these arraylist of hashmap. I want to create an arraylist of hashmap and will change the element of the arraylist in a loop dynamically. My code is as follows:

```
static List<HashMap<Character, Integer>> column = new ArrayList<HashMap<Character, Integer>>(9);
static HashMap<Character, Integer> columns = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)//initialize?
    column.add(i, columns);
for(int i=0;i<9;i++) 
    column.get(i).put(b[xxx][xxx],(int)(b[xxx][xxx]));
```

At first I didn't use the for loop here, I thought I initialize the arraylist size in first line with `(9)` is enough, but when I tried to get element with `column.get(5).put(something)`, it gave me exception with `IndexOutOfBound`.

Then I tried to use the `column.add(i, null);`, but it gave me the exception of `NullPointerException`. So I changed to this `column.add(i, columns);`

But now the problem is, when I tried to edit one of the hashmap in `column` arraylist, every other hashmap in the arraylist will be changed as well, I guess it's because they are set to be the same `columns` hashmap at first?

So my question is how to initialize the arraylist of hashmaps so that I can change every single one of them each time without affecting others?

Answer (score 6):

You don't want to write

```
column.add(i, columns);
```

This keeps adding a reference to the same `HashMap`. `column` will then have 9 references to *the same object*, so when one changes, they all change.

Instead you want

```
column.add(i, new HashMap<Character, Integer>());
```

Then you add a new instance each time.

Comment: @Zip Glad I could help. Also note that you don't need to pass the index `i` unless you are **inserting** at index `i`. If you are just adding to the end of a list you should write `column.add(new HashMap<Character, Integer>());`